# How to configure Django/Apache on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, python, web-server

I am trying to setup my pi as a python web server. I already have Apache/PHP/MySQL running. I can't find the correct way to configure Django on Apache however. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read my note on develop with Django on Pi.
https://github.com/AaronLaw/my-setting/blob/master/Raspberry%20Pi%20setup%20notes.md

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular RPI related issue you are experiencing whilst setting it up? There is [documentation available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) explaining how to setup Apache with Django on Django official web site.

Comment: I tried everything on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.

Comment: and? errors, logs, anything in particular that can explain the problem you are having?

Comment: I just don't know the basics yet. I need to read more about deploying Django application on Apache. I have mod_wsgi configured, and Django installed. I can't find a step by step deployment guide for a novice (python+django) like me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to use Apache? You Pi won't be able to serve a large load of users anyway, so you might be able to run Django in [development mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver);